# Error Installing Pyarrow with Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, numpy, azure-functions, python-3.7, pyarrow

I'm developing a python script to deploy an Azure Function App. For this reason I can't use another Python version to make this easier.

In azure portal I get this error:
[Azure Function app pyarrow module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM50w.png)

When I try to install it via VS Code with pip I get this error: [Error installing Pyarrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv7dV.png)

I managed to make this work using anaconda environment but since my goal is to make it run in an azure function I don't know how to solve this situation.

This is my requirements.txt:

```
arrow-cpp==0.17.*
pyarrow=0.17.*
adal==1.2.2
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
Automat==20.2.0
azure-applicationinsights==0.1.0
azure-batch==4.1.3
azure-common==1.1.24
azure-core==1.5.0
azure-cosmosdb-nspkg==2.0.2
azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6
azure-eventgrid==1.3.0
azure-functions==1.2.0
azure-graphrbac==0.40.0
azure-keyvault==1.1.0
azure-loganalytics==0.1.0
azure-mgmt==4.0.0
azure-mgmt-advisor==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-applicationinsights==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.50.0
azure-mgmt-batch==5.0.1
azure-mgmt-batchai==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-billing==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-cdn==3.1.0
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices==3.0.0
azure-mgmt-commerce==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-compute==4.6.2
azure-mgmt-consumption==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance==1.5.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==2.8.0
azure-mgmt-containerservice==4.4.0
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb==0.4.1
azure-mgmt-datafactory==0.6.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics==0.6.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-datamigration==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-devspaces==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs==2.2.0
azure-mgmt-dns==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-eventgrid==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-eventhub==2.6.0
azure-mgmt-hanaonazure==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-iotcentral==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-iothub==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-iothubprovisioningservices==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault==1.1.0
azure-mgmt-loganalytics==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-logic==3.0.0
azure-mgmt-machinelearningcompute==0.4.1
azure-mgmt-managementgroups==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-managementpartner==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-maps==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-media==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-monitor==0.5.2
azure-mgmt-msi==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-network==2.7.0
azure-mgmt-notificationhubs==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-mgmt-policyinsights==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-powerbiembedded==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms==1.9.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservices==0.3.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup==0.3.0
azure-mgmt-redis==5.0.0
azure-mgmt-relay==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-reservations==0.2.1
azure-mgmt-resource==2.2.0
azure-mgmt-scheduler==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-search==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-servicebus==0.5.3
azure-mgmt-servicefabric==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-signalr==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-sql==0.9.1
azure-mgmt-storage==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-subscription==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager==0.50.0
azure-mgmt-web==0.35.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-servicebus==0.21.1
azure-servicefabric==6.3.0.0
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.6
azure-storage==0.36.0
azure-storage-blob==12.3.1
azure-storage-common==1.4.2
azure-storage-file==1.4.0
azure-storage-file-datalake==12.0.1
azure-storage-queue==1.4.0
beautifulsoup4==4.8.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
cssselect==1.1.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.7
incremental==17.5.0
isodate==0.6.0
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
llvmlite==0.32.0
lxml==4.5.0
mccabe==0.6.1
msrest==0.6.11
msrestazure==0.6.2
numba==0.49.0
numpy==1.18.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==1.0.1
parsel==1.5.2
Protego==0.1.16
proxyscrape==0.3.0
pycparser==2.19
PyHamcrest==2.0.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.4.4
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==1.9.5
thrift==0.13.0
urllib3==1.23
w3lib==1.21.0
wrapt==1.11.2
zope.interface==4.7.1
```

Comment: You should use `pyarrow==0.17.*` instead of `pyarrow=0.17.*`

Comment: As this is a conda requirements file, single `=` are the correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

As you use `conda` as the package manager, you should also use it to install `pyarrow` and `arrow-cpp` using it. In your above output VSCode uses `pip` for the package management. You should consider reporting this as a bug to VSCode. Your current environment is detected as `venv` and not as `conda` environment as you can see in the Python environment box in the lower left.

The best workaround for now is to go to the terminal and manually type in `conda install pyarrow=0.17 arrow-cpp=0.17`. Note that you don't actually need to supply `0.17.*` as `conda` automatically expands `0.17` to `0.17.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

In fact, I think I can't change the environment because this `venv` is actually the environment used by Azure Functions. Is there any way I can use `conda` installed packages in the azure function